# matrixInput in shiny is not showing in quarto interactive document?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, quarto

I am using shinyMatrix package for matrix input. It is working fine inn shiny.
But when I using it for quarto interactive document its not showing the matrix input field.
Below is my sample code.
Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

````
---
title: "Test Doc"
format:
  html:
    page-layout: full
    
server: shiny
---

```{r,message=FALSE}

library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

```

## Running Code



```{r}
numericInput(inputId = "rt",label = "TestNum",value = 1,min = 0,max = 10,step = 1)
matrixInput(inputId = "mat","testMat",value = matrix(0,3,2),inputClass = "",class = "numeric")

```


```{r}
#| context: server


```
````

Comment: I don't if there is a better way to do it, but I've found calling libraries doesn't make their functions available to all chunks in a document. You should be able to fix this by using `shinyMatrix::matrixInput()` instead though.

Answer (score 0):

I never heard of shinyMatrix, it seems like a very minimal implementation, given that it is developed by a single person, is still in beta and has practically no documentation, i would guess it was more of an exercise in package development for the person than an serious tool.

Upon inspection it uses a vue table class for the frontend, which seems to not be usable by observableJS (quarto uses OJS) out ouf the box..

This gives you basically two options if you want to use quarto ( using native shiny would be an option too, since it works fine there.)

option 1: implement a table class in shinyMatrix that is usable by OJS - there seems to be an option to specify a `inputClass`argument in the `matrixInput` function, however its not documented, so you would have to deduct it from the source.

option 2: use one of the established table packages, which allow edits by the user. The gold standard is `DT` which has a editable flag in the render function. `rhandsontable` is editable by default, and a alternative to DT. `reactable` is also an awesome shiny package that works great with quarto, which deserves a honorable mention here - however it sadly doesn't provide an edit functionality out of the box, but it would be possible to make it editable using tooltips / dialogs or similar, there are some examples on the internet, but this again would mean some work.

Here are the main to options `DT` & `rhandsontable` with quarto, the api is similar, and both ship thousands of customizations.

````
---
title: "Test Doc"
format:
  html:
    page-layout: full
    
server: shiny
---

```{r}
#| context: setup
#| include: false
library(rhandsontable)
library(DT)
```

### using DT
```{r}
#| panel: input
DTOutput('tbl')
```


### using rhandsontable
```{r}
#| panel: input
rHandsontableOutput('htbl')
```


```{r}
#| context: server
# datatable
output$tbl = renderDT({
    datatable(matrix(1:10,2,5), editable = T )
    })
# rhansonrtable
output$htbl <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(matrix(1:10,2,5))
  })
```
````

As you can notice the *default* rendering of the table is - opposed to shinyMatrix-  server sided. Unless the table is very large, i don't see any downside to that, you could adapt it however to render in the browser,..